# Line color in ggplot2 by group using geom_segment in calendar image

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use the same figure above, but separating the color of the lines according to the rx variable

```
leuk <- read.dta("http://web1.sph.emory.edu/dkleinb/allDatasets/surv2datasets/anderson.dta")
leuk$Id <- 1:nrow(leuk)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
leuk %>%
  mutate(Id = as.factor(Id),
         status = as.factor(status)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = survt, y = fct_reorder(Id, survt, .desc = TRUE), shape = status, fill = status)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = survt, y = Id, yend = Id)) +
  #geom_vline(xintercept=c(t),linetype="dotted", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(0:max(leuk$survt)),linetype="dotted", alpha = 0.4) + # Una linea dotted en cada "t"
  #geom_vline(xintercept=c(seq(0,10,by=2)),linetype="dotted", alpha = 0.4) + # Una linea en cada "t" par 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1, 16), name = "shapes!") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "white")) +
  #scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 10)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, by = 1)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Id") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))+
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(seq(0,35,by=5)),col='red', alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

Is it possible to color each line according to whether it belongs to the variable rx=0 or rx=1. For example, in the figure the id 14 and 15 that are from group A (rx=0) that the lines are blue, and that those that belong to group B (rx=1) that are red, keeping everything the rest the same
So, rx=0 - blue line;  rx=1 - red line
Thanks in advance

Comment: yes. you haven’t yet defined a color aesthetic. just define it in geom_segment  e. g. `aes(color = rx == 1)` and then `+scale_color_manual(values = c(`TRUE`= „red“, `FALSE`= „blue“))`

Comment: sorry, I forgot how to explicitly write back ticks in markdown. FALSE and TRUE require backticks

Comment: Thanks.It works perfectly:                                                geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = survt, y = Id, yend = Id, col=rx)) +
scale_color_manual(values = c('red','blue')) +  +